# IIS URL rewrite for folder but still allow for specific page match

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need to have url rewrite for all pages under /Blog to my new site newsite.com/blog:

Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Regular Expressions
Pattern:  ^Blog(.*)
Redirect URL: http://mydoamin.com/blog

This works.

But now I would like to add a few specific rewrites  for the page under blog, example:
Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Exact Match
Pattern:  Blog/June-2018/secrutiy-website
Redirect URL: http://mydoamin.com/Blog/June-2018/secrutiy-website

---

The issue is the first rule take over and does not allow for specific pages rewrite under blog.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Move the second rule to top and also stop processing when it hits.

Comment: Thanks. worked 100%